# Proxy server connection reset

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, proxy

My proxy server is a simple Java socket server which listens on port 8081. However, requests are handled a bit different than a regular proxy server.

For example, if I want to open http://www.google.com, I'd type `http://localhost:8081/http://www.google.com`. My server:8081 would open a socket on `http://www.google.com:80`, send the same HTTP headers it received from the browser and then it would return the response from Google to the browser.

But, if for example the browser is expecting a video/mp4 stream, there is a problem. Say the requested page is `http://localhost:8081/http://www.cnn.com/today.mp4`. My server:8081 would then connect to `http://www.cnn.com/today.mp4` with appropriate headers and start receiving the stream. The stream would be read and the chunks (not actually chunked http encoding, chunks of 32768 bytes) would be forwarded to the browser. My server creates a seperate thread for each socket, and the byte read() (from server) and write (to browser) loop is in a try-catch block, so if something fails, the socket is simply closed.

Everything works fine, but the **problem happens here: when the browser requests to forward the video, i.e. to the 5th minute of the video (using the bytes-range header), my server stops working. write() fails and the socket is closed. The next socket accepted cannot be written to (or it can), but the browser request fails (when viewed in Chrome Developer Tools).**

Sorry for the wall of text, I hope you might help me. If necessary, I could post some code but it's a basic multithreaded socket server with a thread per socket.

*Just to clarify, by forwarding the video I mean on fast-forward and/or rewind. Browser uses the bytes-range headers to do this.*

Comment: Is this a timeout thing? Can you tell if `write()` is dying after a specific amount of time?

Comment: It dies almost instantly after the browser requests to forward the video.

Comment: I thought of adding a `sleep()` for a few seconds after accepting the new socket, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried wireshark or fiddler to see what exactly may be getting returned by the remote webserver? That'd probably be my next troubleshooting step.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I get to my workstation. Will let you know if I stumble on anything of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the flash video player requesting the video from server with wrong headers. After tuning it's properties (talking about jwplayer), it works fine.